# start telnet from powershell

Tags: windows, service, command-line

After installed telnet server on win7, using powershell I try to start it:

```
sc config tlntsvr start= demand
```

(this because telnet server is disabled) and then:

```
sc config tlntsvr start= auto
```

I've this error:

```
Set-Content : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'start='.
At line:1 char:3
+ sc <<<<  config TlntSvr start= demand
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-Content], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetContentCommand
```

Comment: Have you tried omitting the space after `=`?

Answer (score 1):

Use Windows command shell for this command, because PowerShell interprets `sc` as the `Set-Content` cmdlet, while it is not in cmd.

Comment: I have no idea why this got two downvotes, because as far as I can tell it's entirely correct. (It might be a bit more helpful if it mentioned workarounds for `sc` within PS, I suppose.)

Comment: I know the community has had a harsh view on semi-reasonable answers that lack structure, content, or depth and down-votes mercilessly/anonymously but I'll stick my hand up here - I seem to have down-voted Hardoman but totally agree with @NathanTuggy's comment - this seems to have been an error on my part - apologies.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is powershell. On the command line, it works fine